# What is the type of foldr map in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to find out what the type of foldr map is, and how you should be solving something like this.

I know what the individual types are:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

I know how the individual functions work, but finding out the type is something I just can't seem to solve.

foldr would take a function as first parameter, which would be the whole of map right?

All tips are welcome, I am new to Haskell and trying to learn puzzles like these.

Comment: In GHCi, you can type `:t foldr map` to derive the type, it then generates: `foldr map :: Foldable t => [a] -> t (a -> a) -> [a]`.

Comment: I know that, I wanna solve it without the compiler

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As ingredients we have `foldr` and `map`. To avoid confusion, let us rename the `a` and `b` of `map` to `c` and `d`, since those are (possibly) different types. So we take as functions:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
map   :: (c -> d) -> [c] -> [d]
```

or more verbose:

```
foldr :: (a -> (b -> b)) -> (b -> ([a] -> b))
map   :: (c -> d) -> ([c] -> [d])
```

Since `map` is the parameter of a function application with `foldr` as function, this means that the type of `map` should be the same as the type of the *parameter* of `foldr`, hence:

```
  a        -> (b   -> b)
~ (c -> d) -> ([c] -> [d])
----------------------------------
a ~ (c -> d), b ~ [c] ~ [d], c ~ d
```

So we have derived that `a` is the same type as `c -> d`, and that `b` is the same type as `[c]` and `[d]`. Therefore we also know that `c ~ d` (`c` is the same type as `d`).

The type of `foldr map` is the *return* type of the `foldr` function, but specialized with the equality relations we have derived, so:

```
foldr map :: b -> ([a] -> b)
```

so we replace `a` with `c -> c`, and `b` with `[c]`, hence the type:

```
foldr map :: [c] -> ([c -> c] -> [c])
```

or in a less verbose form:

```
foldr map :: [c] -> [c -> c] -> [c]
```

> **Note**: the signature of `foldr` has been generalized to `foldr :: Foldable f => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> f a -> b`, but deriving the type is similar.

Comment: Thank you very much! Why is the type of foldr map the return type of foldr?

Comment: @ramonabacherli If `f :: A -> B` and `a :: A` then `f a :: B`.

Comment: oh that rule, I understand now